# UWP Wifi Direct gets exeption code 0x288 (ERROR_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_ERROR)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, wifi-direct

Please support,

I have create a wifi direct sample to connect and transfer data between windows 10 devices but I got an issue: if I use normal wifi (from internet provider) then everything runs normally. But if I use restrict wifi (within a LAN configured by my organization) then I get the exception throws the error ERROR_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_ERROR (The "%hs" encountered an error while applying power or reading the device configuration. This may be caused by a failure of your hardware or by a poor connection).

I searched for the error code (ERROR_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_ERROR) 0x288 then it said the error caused by Windows Update, but I updated the devices following the instruction, but it did not work.

Does anyone have any idea to fix this?

Comment: this happened due to the call "await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(connectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Id);". Does anyone have the same issue? What is the workarround?